# Unable to read binary data as a string on the receive end of a SerialPort transmit

Tags: arrays, encoding, .net-core, serial-port, base64

Still not sure what the title for this question is...

I'm leveraging off of the .Net framework by using `serialPort.ReadExisting()` (which returns a string) rather than `serialPort.Read()` (which returns a byte array). The reason I'm doing this is because `serialPort.ReadExisting()` gives me access to the stream data that isn't yet in the buffer along with the SerialPort buffer. However, this method requires that I read the data as a string, but there doesn't seem to be a way to tell the serial port "Hey use base64 Encoding" and instead my options are ASCII, UTF8 etc. `serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;`. Now, I know my data isn't the problem because this TEST works:

```
                string a = Convert.ToBase64String(transmitBytes, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
                byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(a);
                SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create();
                byte[] hash1 = sha256.ComputeHash(transmitBytes);
                byte[] hash2 = sha256.ComputeHash(b);
                if (CompareHash(hash1, hash2))
                    Console.WriteLine("good check");
            }
            private static bool CompareHash(byte[] a1, byte[] a2)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (a1[i] != a2[i])
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

But if I send my data over the wire, I get problems. My theory is that this is because the ReadExisting() method is trying to read the bits as 7bit ascii values and many parts of data would be outside of the range of 6 bit base64 characters: stuff like `[`, `_`, and `|` would cause a problem, which could happen if the receiving end is trying to read 7 bits rather than 6.

I've tried to set up the serial communication in a low noise environment, and I've tried several combinations of data lengths to send per serial message.

The offending relevant code is below (last line throws exception):

```
    // sending machine is working I think
    serialPort.DataBits = 8; //also tried (6 and 7) many many times)
    _serialPort.Write(Convert.ToBase64String(transmitBytes, Base64FormattingOptions.None));

    // receiver machine is trowing the format exception
    serialPort.DataBits = 8; // also tried (6 and 7) many many times)
    byte[] BigBuffer = new byte[_serialPort.ReadBufferSize];
    // read data then discard buffer to get new data from the transmitting machine
    BigBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(_serialPort.ReadExisting()); // throws exception
```

Any idea how I can debug, and hopefully fix what is happening? I don't want to resort to serialPort.Read()

```
exception.Message = "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."
```

Additional test scenario:
I sent over a small unrealistic string of values for debugging purposes and got the same exception. I HAD TO HAVE THE SENDER LOOP ITS SENDING SO IT IS SENDING THIS VALUE SEVERAL TIMES BEFORE THE RECEIVER HITS THE EXCEPTION.
Here is the original string base64:

```
utz+EDJUdpgLAAAATG9yZSBpbXBzdW3UAPpp4FQlifaZAzUzyh25062szzbhSyVs3ehe6nU+UYlnRSMB782r
```

Here is the received string from ReadExisting() (I assume this is ASCII since the serialPort is set to ASCII encoding). This string causes an exception when passed to Convert.FromBase64String()

```
dW3UAPpp4FQlifaZAzUzyh25062szzbhSyVs3ehe6nU+UYlnRSMB782rutz+EDJUdpgLAAAATG9yZSBpbXBzdW3UAPpp4FQlifaZAzUzyh25062szzbhSyVs3ehe6nU+UYlnRSMB782rutz+EDJUdpgLAAAATG9yZSBpbXBzdW3UAPpp4FQlifaZAzUzyh25062szzbhSyVs3ehe6nU+UYlnR
```

Comment: Could you show us the Base64 before and after transfer? This would help nail down where the issue is.

Comment: @Christopher It's a 1.5mb jpg file

Comment: Okay, that would be a bit long. But I fear we can not help you without seeing *how* the base64 string is mangeled. Maybe try some other data instead? Maybe a short sentence you encode to byte and then send over this? I know it feels wrong (and it would be in normal use), but this is nessesary for debugging.

Comment: Of course, you could just take some classical placeholder stuff like "TG9yZSBpbXBzdW0=", aka "Lore impsum". At least according to this converter https://www.base64encode.org/

Comment: @Christopher did the test. Check it out if you have time. I had to have the sender keep looping to get the exception with that test. Another thing to note is that the buffer might be overwritten which may have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

> I HAD TO HAVE THE SENDER LOOP ITS SENDING SO IT IS SENDING THIS VALUE SEVERAL TIMES BEFORE THE RECEIVER HITS THE EXCEPTION.

Then this is a issue with Error Detection/Correction. Effectively what you are doing here is working directly on Layer 2 to 4 of the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_architecture). The kind of layers you usually do not deal with. The average programmer only ever deals with layers 7, 6 and (for HTTP) 5.

There are actually multiple layers of error prevention, correction and detection in the entire stack. There are only 2 real options:

1. Stop trying to work on this level. Get someone elses prooven code so you can go back to layer 7-5, the average programmers workspace.
2. Reimplement all that error detection, prevention and correction yourself. Wich is a whole lot more complex then plain old sending.

Comment: Well, I don't have this problem when I send raw bytes. It's just when I'm reading as base64 string. No exception happens at all with raw bytes. Only reason I'm not doing that at the moment is because I need the ReadAvailable() method

Comment: @Goku How do you verify the bytes are transfered properly? Base64 has a sort-of-but-not-really error detection. Accidental, unreliable error detection. It will only ignore changes of up to 63 numbers. But the byte transfer has no error detection. Well, maybe during the JPG being interpreted, but that is way to late.

Comment: because I'm sending a header trailer and a hash so that is how I verified the data was untouched by noise or software. I saw that base64string class did have an error detection (as seen by the exception), but I'm not sure what part of this is triggering the exception. I know somthing is causing this my data to not be the same as transmitted. I guess my goal is to have the SerialPort class read the string as base64 rather than 7bit ascii

Answer (score 0):

The error message is probably not appropriate.
However, it is true that the parameter string passed to `Convert.FromBase64String()` does not match the base64 specification.

If the last string you gave is exactly the parameter you passed to `Convert.FromBase64String()`, its length is **217**, it is not a multiple of **4**, and does not meet the base64 specification.

Therefore, it may have caused an exception.

[Convert.FromBase64String(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=netframework-4.8)

> **Exceptions**
>   **FormatException**
>   The length of `s`, ignoring white-space characters, **is not zero or a multiple of 4.**
>
> -or-
>
> The format of `s` is invalid. `s` contains a non-base-64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space-character among the padding characters.

Rather than simply converting binary data to base64 and sending/receiving it, add some data that can check whether all the data has been received, or divide long data into short units and attach check data in the same way Please devise such as sending and receiving.

Comment: At the end of the question article, I copied and pasted the string presented as a parameter to Convert.FromBase64String() and counted it. Since my language environment is Japanese, there may have been some conversion.